# signTransaction not working

Tags: web3js, sendsignedtransaction

I'm trying to sign a txs using web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction but it gives :

```
v: '0x00',
r: '0x00000000000000000000',
s: '0x00000000000000000000',
```

I tried the examples from official documentation at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction but using

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction({
    to: '0xF0109fC8DF283027b6285cc889F5aA624EaC1F55',
    value: '1000000000',
    gas: 2000000
}, '0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318')
.then(console.log);
```

also results in same response instead of

```
 v: '0x25',
    r: '0xc9cf86333bcb065d140032ecaab5d9281bde80f21b9687b3e94161de42d51895',
    s: '0x727a108a0b8d101465414033c3f705a9c7b826e596766046ee1183dbc8aeaa68',
```

which is mentioned in the documentation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of web3 are you using? How are you testing? For new versions the documentation is here https://docs.web3js.org/api/web3-eth-accounts/function/signTransaction.